# Which kanji is this: 氵+ 十?

Tags: meaning

氵and 十 are the left and right components and the kanji is shown in "Spirited away" but I can't find it in any dictionary.

Thank you in advance

Comment: FYI: Some dictionaries (e.g. LINE Dict, although its quality is occasionally rather suspect) have character recognition. Zhongwen.com is only for traditional characters, but IIRC allows you to look up characters if you know some of their components. (I've only used the print version before, and only sparingly, but I imagine the web version to be similar.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Japanese

Comment: Well, japanese use chinese characters, isn't it ?

Comment: @Boctulus: IIRC Japanese kanji [does not always match up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji#Kokuji) with characters used in Chinese.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

汁 - Chinese zhi1, Japanese しる - in Chinese, it means juice, but in Japanese, it can mean juice, sap, or soup broth.